# Chern Insulator in Magnetic Field

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, insulators

Recently I was reading the book *"Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors"* by Andrei. Bernevig & Taylor Hughes and in section 8.7, Chern Insulator in Magnetic Field, a Hamiltonian has been written something like this:
[image]

I have no idea why the form of Hamiltonian is like this?
For start, by considering a constant magnetic field $B_{z}$, I just took a gauge in $y$ direction and entered vector potential to the lattice generalization of a continuum Dirac Hamiltonian:

$
\sin(p_{x})\sigma_{x} + \sin(p_{y})\sigma_{y} + (2+M-\cos(p_{x})-\cos(p_{y}))\sigma_{z}\\ \to \quad
\sin(p_{x})\sigma_{x} + \sin(p_{y}-eA_{2})\sigma_{y} + (2+M-\cos(p_{x})-\cos(p_{y}-eA_{2}))\sigma_{z}
$

where $\sigma_{i}$'s are Pauli's matrices and $M$ is mass. After expanding above equation around $k_{x},k_{y} \approx 0$, I reached to a different result. Is there any mistake in my calculations?